# Multiple Undefined References - Qt Creator - vJoy C++

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, virtual, joystick

#### Edit

It was pointed out that I should be using **MS VC++** rather than **MinGW**, this seems to result in a different issue for me:

**2 Unresolved External Symbols**

1. **__imp_SetWindowsHookExW**
2. **__imp_UnhookWindowsHookEx**

As seen here:
[image: image1]

Each of these trace into **WinUser.h** here:

[image: img2]

Should I make and entirely new post for this? - or revise the current post?

---

### Original Post :

I'm trying to **re-build** a program which maps Mouse input to a *"Virtual Joy Stick"* using libraries from [vJoy](http://vjoystick.sourceforge.net/site/index.php/77-vjoy/84-homepage-v200)

The **original project** can be found here: [MouseToJoystick](https://github.com/raptorswing/MouseToJoystick)

I have not changed anything in the program, and I am attempting to compile it within **QT Creator**, using **QT 5.10.0** - I am not certain if I have the *"Build Settings"* setup correctly.

---

Here is the current list of compile **Warnings and Errors**:

[image: Qt Creator Errors (*image*)]

As far as I can tell, each of the **"undefined references"** listed is a function which can be traced into **"vJoyInterface.h"** which is included in the file **"MainWindow.cpp"** where the *"undefined references"* take place.

[image: Project **Directory** Structure (*image*)]

[**MainWindow.cpp** #includes (*image*)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfalr.png)

And here are the "prototypes" for the function said to be "undefined" in the **"vJoyInterface.h"** file:

[vJoyInterface Header (*image*)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aytQS.png)

---

So, at the very least the "prototypes" for the functions exist - although the functions may still be undefined - other answers I've seen say that the project need to somehow **include/link** the appropriate library that contains the definitions for the functions.

The only other files related to **vJoy** are in the "**vJoyLib/64**" and "**vJoyLib/32**" folder. Which both contain these files:

[image: vJoyLib folder Libraries (*image*)]

This library is referenced in the "**MouseToJoystick.pro**" file, as seen here:

[image: Qt Project Linking vJoyInterface (*image*)]

My assumption is that the vJoy functions are defined somewhere in the "**vJoyInterface.lib**" but I have no idea, and I don't know how to check.

---

## TL;DR

QT Creator says there are **"undefined references"** but I know the prototypes have been *included*, and I assume that they are defined in a library linked to the project as seen in this image:

[Qt Project Linking vJoyInterface (*image*)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckSbE.png)

But I honestly have no idea where the functions are actually defined, or if the library is being linked correctly.

---

## Questions

1. How can I figure out where the functions are actually being defined **OR** how can I properly include the library/definitions in my project?
2. Why do each of the functions have '**_imp__**' added on the beginning in the error message?

---

#### Additional Information

[Qt Creator - Project Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0gGu.png) - **Qt 5.10.0 MinGW** 32bit

Comment: Sometimes, when you compile before adding libraries and you recompile, the .o files are not changed again. It happend me a lot of time. I deleted the debug or release folder and compiled again

Comment: Yea, I've been using "**Clean All**" and "**Rebuild All**" options in QT creator, so all the files should be fresh - (have also used "**Run qmake**" which I've seen suggested in some other questions, to correct include/link library errors)

Comment: The library is complied with MS VC++ and you try to link it with project that uses MinGW. There ways to make it work but you don't want to make it that complicated. Instead try to use same compiler for all three Qt, app and lib part.

Comment: @AlexanderVX I see, yes I had Originally set it up with **MS VC++** (as QT had suggested) However I ran into a different problem, you can see in this image: [2 Unresolved External Symbols](https://i.imgur.com/kZWOqnv.png) 

I will update my post to reflect this issue

Comment: Instead for enabling `SetWindowHookEx` you should do `LIBS += -luser32` in the project file.

Comment: That appears to work, Thank you! 

Simply added that line to my project file, >Clean All, >Run qMake

Now the program compiles and runs, Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AlexanderVX provided this answer in a comment to my question

After switching from **MinGW** to **MS VC++** in the project compile settings, I added 1 line of code to my "**MouseToJoystick.pro**" file.

**Here is the new line of code:**

Project File code (*image*)

[image]

After that I did "Clean All", "Run Qmake", and "Rebuild All" as seen in this image:

Steps (*image*)

[image]

The program compile and runs perfectly, thank you @AlexanderVX